# UIViewController handling rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uikit

My app is configured in the info plist such that it only supports portrait orientation.

[image]

In the root view controller though, I would like to rotate to all of the possible orientations.

My code is:

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
// rotate to any orientation
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
```

}

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
// should auto rotate is fine. I don't care though...
return YES;
}

- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
// Method is not called
[super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

// Code here will execute before the rotation begins.
// Equivalent to placing it in the deprecated method -[willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:]

[coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {

    // Place code here to perform animations during the rotation.
    // You can pass nil or leave this block empty if not necessary.

} completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {

    // Code here will execute after the rotation has finished.
    // Equivalent to placing it in the deprecated method -[didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:]

}];
}
```

The method `supportedInterfaceOrientations` is called but the actual orientation doesn't change

Here you can see that the breakpoints are called

[image]

But at the end of the day the view controller stays in the "portrait" orientation even though the device is in landscape.

In this simple example you can tell by the status bar position.

[image]

Comment: Why in the plist you have set only for Portrait orientation is there any reason?

Comment: Customers code. They are integrating our code. And our VC is presented in its own window so our view controller is a root view controller of its window, so per documentation it should rotate.

Comment: Can it be tried by adding the below code in AppDelegate                                                - (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(nullable UIWindow *)window{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}